# Drupal form ajax submit not working

Tags: ajax, drupal

The drupal form that i submit has ajax property defined

```
 '#submit' => array(),
  '#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'form_submit',
  'wrapper' => 'problem-wrapper',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'effect' => 'fade',

  $form['#validate'][] = 'problem_form_validate';
```

but it does the validation only on second click of the submit button. The first time i submit it shows the please wait...

throbber but nothing happens. The second time I click the button it works. What could be the possible reason. This is happening on a specific environment. on some other environment it is not and issue.

What could possibly be in the settings of an environment that forces the validate function to be called only on the second submit.

Thanks,